# Should I deploy a dynamic page on Amazon s3?

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm currently developing a dynamic webpage using React, it also uses axios, react-router and other stuff. I'm aware that Amazon s3 can be used to deploy static pages but I tried uploading my app in it and it seems to work just fine. So my questions is: is it ok to use s3 for a dynamic page? or maybe im not understanding what a static page is? I think a static page is just plain html with maybe a little bit of javascript for animations but no api calls nor big libraries like React.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're misunderstanding the difference between a static and a dynamic website. A `dynamic` website is one that is rendered on the server, using some sort of server side language such as PHP, Nodejs, etc. A `static` website is any website that does not use a server side language for rendering so that your entire website is static and the physical assets do not actually change. When you build your React app, it uses JavaScript to dynamically change the page content, however the html that is output, and even the JavaScript itself never actually changes.

To add to this, it is completely okay to deploy React applications and other sorts of JavaScript based web applications. This is actually a common use case, and one that I've used S3 for in the past as well.